# How can I quickly fetch or grab sfdx auth url?

Tags: salesforcedx, authentication, url, auth

I want to know my sfdx auth url to transfer it to another machine or use as Github Secret key. I have about 10+ different Developer Edition, Sandboxes and Devhub environments which I need in my CI/CD process.

It requires a long time to manually execute `sfdx force:org:display  --verbose` command for every environment and then manually grab and find SFDX Auth URL from the response to copy and paste it into Github Secrets.

Can I automate this or make it more easy to grab the SFDX Auth URL from the command response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `JQ` tool to quickly grab the SFDX Auth URL from the command using `--json` switch.

Still you need to authorize the env

`sfdx force:auth:web:login -a al -r https://test.salesforce.com` for sandbox or skip `-r` parameter for production/Developer Edition environment and substitute `al` with actual desired `alias` for the org; and then use `--json` parameter and pass the result to `jq` command

`sfdx force:org:display -u al --verbose --json | jq '.result.sfdxAuthUrl' -r`

To install `jq`, use `brew install jq` on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary info with respect to @patlatus answer:

The following command can help to obtain the SFDX Auth URL in a temporary file in your local folder. The authorization to the environment is a pre-requisite here as well.

`sfdx org:display --target-org alias --verbose --json > authFile.json`

where `alias` is your org alias and `authFile.json` is the file generated after running the command.
Then open the `authFile.json` file to retrieve the sfdxAuthUrl value.
You can delete the file locally afterwards